# Invoking property or type from name

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am trying to dynamically set a resource string. The name of the resource varies slightly depending on a code that comes back from a web service. A different code should show a different message to the user.

Instead of a huge if structure, or a dictionary, is there a nice way I can do this using reflection, or some other black magic. This sort of thing:

```
var message = Something.Invoke("HostedResources.MESSAGE_CODE_" + code);
```

Thanks

Comment: but, is this web service hosted in IIS application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use a reflection to get the property by name:

```
HostedResources hostedResourceInstance = GetHostedResources();

PropertyInfo info = typeof(HostedResources).GetProperty("MESSAGE_CODE_" + code);
var message = (string)info.GetValue(hostedResourceInstance, null);
```